# Unable to login into a site using www:Mechanize

Tags: perl

I am using WWW:Mechanize to try to login to a site.

Code

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get("https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/homepage.html/");
$mech->submit_form(
form_name => 'yaSignIn',
fields => {
email => 'email',
qpassword=> 'pass'
}
);


print $mech->content();
```

However it is not being logged into the site. What am i doing wrong. The website redirects and says please enable cookies to continue. How do i do that .

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting this block before your get.

```
$mech->cookie_jar(
        HTTP::Cookies->new(
            file           => "cookies.txt",
            autosave       => 1,
            ignore_discard => 1,
    )
);
```

**SuperEdit2**: I just tried this myself and it seemed to work. Give it a try.(changed the form number to 3 and added an agent alias)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

# Create a new instance of Mechanize
my $bot = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$bot->agent_alias( 'Linux Mozilla' );
# Create a cookie jar for the login credentials
$bot->cookie_jar(
        HTTP::Cookies->new(
            file           => "cookies.txt",
            autosave       => 1,
            ignore_discard => 1,
    )
);
# Connect to the login page
my $response = $bot->get( 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/homepage.html/' );
# Get the login form. You might need to change the number.
$bot->form_number(3);
# Enter the login credentials.
$bot->field( email => 'email' );
$bot->field( password => 'pass' );
$response = $bot->click();

print $response->decoded_content;
```

Comment: That doesnt work. It still displays that cookies need to be enabled.

Comment: Did you try the new edited block? Edit: Check that qpassword part. There doesn't seem to be any 'qpassword' in the source of the site. But I'm assuming that was just a transfer typo?

Comment: Yes. That doesnt work too. I have no clue why. Yes. I put qpassword to password.

Comment: I just did a test with the code above. I saved the decoded_content to a html file and when I open it, I appear to be logged in. So, give this one a try and good luck.

Comment: Just an added observation- If i add a new url 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage?ie=UTF8&ref_=gno_yam_myk#pdocSettings' and save it as html it gets stuck at loading please wait. Any ideas why.